# Ramme instagram client does not open

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

I've recently installed "Ramme" Instagram client on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop and it's not starting. Can someone tell me how to fix this? I can't open it by clicking. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Ramme is an unofficial Instagram desktop app built with Electron, but it is no longer being maintained. instagramport is another unofficial Instagram desktop app built with Electron that can be installed from Ubuntu Software or from the terminal with the following command:

```
sudo snap install instagramport  
sudo snap connect:instagramport:camera :camera
```

Features:

- Supports direct message feature
- Lets you upload pictures
- Filters, Boomerang and other fancy features are not yet supported.
- New message notifications are not supported yet.